# Is there any way to know if someone has logged into my email through OWA?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

If I am logged on to my work email (MS Outlook) through the network and someone simultaneously accesses said work email through OWA..is there any way that I can get a notification or alert on Outlook that someone else has logged on to my email?

Comment: No. As a normal user you wouldn't have the capability even if it was possible.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response...however, what do you mean I "wouldn't have the capability even if it was possible"? Could IT even monitor this kind of activity?

Comment: I assumed since you were asking this question you were not the system administrator and thus wouldn't be able to setup this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If your system administrator configures the logging of access to IIS server and

will parse the records like

`http://<ip address>/exchange/<user name>`
 or

`http://<ip address>/exchange/<user name>@<domane name>.<suffix>`

in folders `windir%\system32\Logfiles\W3SVC1` and
then will send you a report, it will be something that you need.